# Sagemaker Batch transform with multiple images

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

The batch transform with mini-batch > 1 of images doesn't work fo as I expect.

I'm using Sagemaker Batch transform for inference.
I'm trying to preprocess images on a custom container that I created (using model pipelining: the first model is the pre-processor that I'm asking about, and the second model is an Nvidia-triton inference server).

I'm using batch transform as follows:

```
transformer = sagemaker.transformer.Transformer(model_name=model_name, 
                  instance_count=instance_count, 
                  instance_type=instance_type,
                  max_concurrent_transforms=16,
                  output_path=inference_output_data,
                  strategy='MultiRecord')
transformer.transform(data=batch_input,
                  content_type='image/jpeg',
                  job_name=job_name,
                  split_type='Line',
                  wait=False,
                  logs=False)
```

Note the `split type` and `strategy` with values 'MultiRecord' and 'Line' so I would get mini-batches > 1.

When I did my sanity check with batch size of 1, the following code worked fine:

```
@app.route('/invocations', methods=['POST'])
def transformation():
    img_bytes = flask.request.data
    img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img_bytes))
    preprocessed_image = preprocess_image()
```

However, with batching, this code doesn't work anymore. Basically I would not expect it to work, since it only valid for reading for one image.
I even printed the bytes that my container receives and these are not the original bytes of the image but some strange mix of the images.

Can you please point me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the code below -

```
transformer.transform(data=batch_input,
                  content_type='image/jpeg',
                  job_name=job_name,
                  split_type='Line',
                  wait=False,
                  logs=False)
```

I see that your input is using type "image/jpeg" but you set your `split_type` as `Line`, this method works well when you have lets say a large CSV/Parquet file with the `delimiter` as line and when you want to process multiple lines at a time, you can use the `MultiLine` strategy to read multiple lines at a time. Furthermore, you can have multiple instances and more smaller chunks of file to process them in parallel or distributed fashion. Let's say you have 10 input files and 2 instances, then each instance processes 5 files and speeds up your BT job.

Coming back to your scenario, I don't think BT is a good fit, given that you are not going to utilizing the native capabilities of the service. I would recommend to check out SageMaker Async Inference that works with larger payloads( in the order of GBs) and furthermore, it allows you to scale down the number of instances to Zero and maximize your compute resources.

Attaching a blog [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/run-computer-vision-inference-on-large-videos-with-amazon-sagemaker-asynchronous-endpoints/) that can help

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I thought that BT was the best fit for me since I don't need real time, and I would get ~50k input images per individual request. For that, BT is most helpful in batching all inputs. 
Can you please elaborate more why you wrote that I would not "utilize the native capabilities of the service"?

Comment: What i mean by some of the native capabilities are namely -  BT has built-in features to make working with structured data easier and optimizations to automatically distribute structured data. For example, using a strategy such as `MultiLine` to process multiple records at the same time. Ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTransformJob.html#API_CreateTransformJob_RequestSyntax and also, the ability to use mini batches to process request etc